# Idempotent consumer with JDBC repository Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp, camel-sql

i am working on springboot with Apache Camel so my question is how can i write code to use Idempotentconsumer with JDBC repository using apache camel.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is implement

```
#queryForInt(T key)
#insert(T key)
#delete(T key)
```

methods of `AbstractJdbcMessageIdRepository` from `camel-sql`

define your bean

```
    <bean id="idempotentRepository"
          class="yourpackage.YourJDBCIdempotentRepository">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="your-datasource-bean-ref"/>
    </bean>
```

add in route

```
    <route id="your-route">
        <from uri="ftp:your-endpoint?idempotent=true&idempotentRepository=#idempotentRepository"/>
        ...
    </route>
```

Refer : http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.10.0/camel-sql/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/idempotent/jdbc/AbstractJdbcMessageIdRepository.html

Comment: Would using the standard JdbcMessageIdRepository also work in a distributed environment with multiple nodes? If I look at the "Idempotent Consumer" Camel page (https://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html) I can see that HazelcastIdempotentRepository works in a clustered environment, but is this also the caser the JdbcMessageIdRepository? When looking at the code of this component in GitHub i cannot see any lock statements (or whatever) to guarantee synchronized access? If anybody can confirm this that would be great!

Comment: @KimZeevaarders - I guess you should try it out. There is some unique constraint you have to add to the camel_messageprocessed table (if using jdbc repo) - see the doco. Seems to work well though.